# Ssh into amazon lightsail container service running container

Tags: docker, amazon-lightsail, lightsail-container-service

I'm totally stumped on how to approach this.

I have two running containers on amazon lightsails container service. But I have no idea on how to access them with SSH.

Is this even possible? I need the commandline to check some stuff in the running container.

On the container I want to access I have an open port 22.

Comment: A container is usually a wrapper around a single process.  What processes are running inside these containers?  Do those processes expose an ssh-compatible interface?

Comment: Indeed, this is a webapplication (laravel) and it;s running inside an alpine based container.

Comment: The container is probably only running something like the PHP-FPM server and not an ssh daemon.  You can't ssh into it any more than you could ssh into the PHP process on your local system.